# jquery - item clone when it's sort

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm using Jquery sortable.

My code allow user to drag and drop from stock to number of baskets. when he drop item to sascket the item does NOT delete from stock and it's good.
it's working fine

The problem is that i also allow user to sort the item inside every basket and when he do that the script clone the item, and it's not good

What should i do?

```
$( ".attrac" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".dropZone",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"           
});


$(document).ready(function() {  

    $( ".dropZone" ).sortable({
        revert: true,
        update: function(event, ui) {

            $.ajax ({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'ajax/secs-control.php',
              data: data,
              dataType: 'json',
              async: false,
              success: function (data) 
                  {


                  }
              });

        }               

    });

    defineDragItems();


} );
```

HTML

```
<div class="well dropZone" id="sec12">
    Drag & drop here                    
    <div class="panel panel-info attrac ui-widget-content fadeSec" data-id="attrac-2" >

        <div class="panel-heading">
            The World  Remembrance
            <span class="pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="delBtn-attrac2sec text-danger" data-attracID="2" data-secID="12" data-pos="2"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">Plan a memorable visit</div>

    </div>  

    <div class="panel panel-info attrac ui-widget-content fadeSec" data-id="attrac-43" >

        <div class="panel-heading">
            Header of second item
            <span class="pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="delBtn-attrac2sec text-danger" data-attracID="43" data-secID="12" data-pos="3"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">body second item</div>

    </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I separate my drag item class:

```
$( ".attrac-clone" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".dropZone",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"           
});

$( ".attrac-unique" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".dropZone",
    helper: "original",
    revert: "invalid"           
});
```